# How to divide input by 2 then round up

Tags: assembly, x86

I don't fully understand the div concept in assembler, all I know is that the quotient gets stored in EAX and the remainder in EDX. But i'm trying to figure out how to divide a user input by 2 and if there's a remainder then round it up. For example:

- N= 3 / 2 = 1.5 Rounded up to 2
- N= 9 / 2 = 4.5 Rounded up to 5
- N= 4 / 2 = 2

Comment: Add 1 before you divide. And if you are dividing by 2 don't: just shift to the right one bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To divide by two, you shift the register right one place. The low bit is shifted into the Carry flag.

So if the number is even, 0 is shifted into CF. If the number is odd, 1 is shifted into CF.

So, to divide by two and round up, you shift right one place, then add the value of the carry flag:

```
; assume that the value is in EAX
shr eax, 1   ; divide by 2. Low bit into Carry flag
adc eax, 0   ; add the value of the Carry flag
```

Comment: Wow so simple haha, I didn't know you're able to add the CF. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Except for the case where the numerator is the maximum value, you can round up by adding 1 before dividing by 2. Examples

```
6 / 2 = 3.0       (6 + 1) / 2 = 3    // remains the same
7 / 2 = 3.5       (7 + 1) / 2 = 4    // is rounded up
```

In the general case, if you want to divide by `n` and round up, add `n / 2` or `n >> 1` before dividing. Where `n` is even, the result is obviously good. Where `n` is odd it works like this example dividing by 5, where you add `5 / 2`, ie 2

```
5 / 5 = 1.0       (5 + 2) / 5 = 1    // remains the same
6 / 5 = 1.2       (6 + 2) / 5 = 1    // rounded down
7 / 5 = 1.4       (7 + 2) / 5 = 1    // rounded down
8 / 5 = 1.6       (8 + 2) / 5 = 2    // rounded up
9 / 5 = 1.8       (9 + 2) / 5 = 2    // rounded up
```

Comment: This breaks when adding `n/2` overflows. For example in a 16-bit integer, adding 1 to 0xFFFF will give you 0, which when divided by 2 gives you . . . 0. But shifting right and then adding the carry flag will give you the correct answer of 0x8000.

Comment: @JimMischel that is what I said in the very first sentence. The carry flag solution only works with shifting to divide by 2.

Comment: I have always thought it bad form for an answerer to comment negatively on other answers, some even have the gall to downvote other answers.

Comment: @JimMischel there was no need to repeat your answer here in comment - I did read it. However, since you answered the explicit question, I upvoted yours.

Comment: Pretty sure that what you described is general rounding, not rounding up. To round up, you add `n - 1` and then shift right by log2(n), unless I'm mistaken. `0 / 256 => 255 / 256 = 0`, `1 / 256 => 256 / 256 = 1`,  `257 / 256 => 512 / 256 = 2`, `2500 / 256 => 2755 / 256 = 10`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
N = (3 + 2 - 1) / 2

xor  edx, edx
add  eax, ecx
dec  eax
div  ecx
```

Or if 2 is a constant:

```
inc  eax
shr  eax, 1
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot to think about here:

- Will the number overflow if you add one before the divide?
- Do you need to handle negative numbers?
- The `div` operation is expensive, `shr` is much faster

`shr` is divide by two and floor for unsigned numbers

`sar` is divide by two and floor for signed numbers

The bit that is shifted out goes into the carry flag, so to round you can add it back.

Comment: Thanks, im new to the language and didn't know about the shr and sar